# Vue JS ignore if and else if code and jump straight to else

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I have a code for detecting the type that has been input and put into an array. somehow the code ignore the if and else if and jump into the else command

For inputting the type

```html
<!-- Type Input -->

  <select v-model="exType">
    <option v-for="option in typeOption"> {{option}} </option>
  </select>
```

Adding the inputted and putting it into an array

```js
    typeOption: ['Income', 'Primer', 'Skunder', 'Tersier'],

  },
  methods: {
    addExpense(exType) {
      this.expenseList.unshift({
          type: this.exType,
        }),
        this.exType = '',
    },
```

For detecting the type

```js
getType(type) {
  if (type.toLowerCase() == "income") {
    this.class = "blue"
    return this.class
  } else if (type.toLowerCase() == "primer") {
    this.class = "green"
    return this.class
  } else if (type.toLowerCase() == "skunder") {
    this.class = "orange"
    return this.class
  } else {
    this.class = "red"
    return this.class
  }
}
```

and the CSS class

```css
<style scoped>
        .blue{
          background-color:#87CEFA;
        }
        .green{
          background-color:#90EE90;
        }
        .orange{
          background-color:#FFA07A;
        }
        .red{
          background-color:#F08080;
        }
    </style>
```

I have scratched my head on why does this happen

Edit :
the get type is called when the table is created

```html
<tbody>
  <tr :class="getType(`${expenseList.type}`)" v-for="data in expenseList">
    <td> The Data </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byYAt.png)

Comment: Can you show how `getType` is called and how exactly its result is used?

Comment: I have added it, its called when the body is created

Comment: Try to replace `getType(\`${expenseList.type}\`)` by `getType(data.type)` for some reactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `` getType(`${expenseList.type}`) `` breaks reactivity.
To save reactivity use `getType(expenseList.type)`.

Also, I see issue in this code. It seems to me that there must be `getType(data.type)`.

Also, if it is not really necessary, you can get rid of the first by simply returning the desired result.

```js
getType(type) {
  if (type.toLowerCase() == "income") {
    return "blue"
  } else if (type.toLowerCase() == "primer") {
    return "green"
  } else if (type.toLowerCase() == "skunder") {
    return "orange"
  } else {
    return "red"
  }
}
```